# How to draw to google charts in one div?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, frontend, google-visualization

I'm using google Charts API to draw some charts of my data. I have something like:

Obj1: At1, at2, etc.
Obj2: ...
Objx:

So, i don't know how many objets come from the web service i'm using. How can i draw more than one google chart inside of a single div? I have this:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
for (var i = 0, len = vessels.vessel.length; i < len; i++) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Vessel');
    data.addColumn('number', 'RPM');
    data.addRow([
        vessels.vessel[i].vesselname,
        parseFloat(vessels.vessel[i].rpm)
    ]);
    chart.draw(data);
}
```

But only draw the last item. Any help?